# Android: Picasso enlarging Image on Click?

Tags: java, android, mobile, picasso, image-enlarge

I was using Picasso for a while now and I'm very satisfied with it. However I'm in need of enlarging an imageview's image which was loaded by Picasso. As in, I simply want to create a [zoomImageFromThumb](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) of the image. However the traditional [zoomImageFromThumb](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) requires a resource to be present in the project. In my case, Picasso loads it up.. so how do I enlarge an image laoded by Picasso on click of the image view?

My code so far:

```
ImageBanner= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lb_single_image);
Picasso.with(ctx)
        .load("www.flickr.com/randomimage.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.error_placeholder)
        .into(ImageBanner);
ImageBanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //how do I enlarge the picasso image?
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well, one option is to stretch the image and put it in the center of the software , and then add in this animation.

Comment: Hmm any idea on how to do that sir please? @emigrantdd

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setOnClickListener()` you can use `PhotoViewAttacher`:

```
    ImageBanner= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lb_single_image);
Picasso.with(ctx)
        .load("www.flickr.com/randomimage.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.error_placeholder)
        .into(ImageBanner);

PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(ImageBanner);
```

Only one line, and it will works.